# Уведомление, которое не исчезает после закрытия приложения

Tags: android, android-service, android-notification

В операции (`Activity`) я несколько раз шлю запросы сервису, наследующемуся от `IntentService`:

```
int peopleCount = people.size();
int cur = 0;
for (Person person : people) {
    cur++;
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MailService.class);
    intent.putExtra("LAST", cur == peopleCount);
    startService(intent);
}
```

Сам сервис выглядит следующим образом:

```
public class MyService extends IntentService {
    final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 10;

    public MyService() {
        super("MyService");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Notification notification =                getNotification(getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.notification_about));
        updateNotification(notification);
        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable final Intent intent) {
         final boolean last = intent.getBooleanExtra("LAST", false);
         ...
         if (last) {
                try {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "TRYING TO KILL NOTIFICATION");
                    NotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    nMgr.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Exception: ", ex);
                }
            }
          }
    }

    private void updateNotification(Notification notification) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    }

    private Notification getNotification(String text){
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                        0,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );
        return new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_main)           
.setContentTitle(getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText(text)
                .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                .build();
    }
}
```

Т.е. я хочу при первом запуске сервиса создавать уведомление, а когда метод `onHandleIntent()` выполняется последний раз - я хочу, чтобы уведомление исчезало (из области уведомлений и из панели уведомлений). И данный код вроде бы  работает так, как нужно... Но только в случае, если ничего не делать. Т.е., если ничего не нажимать, уведомление сначала появляется в области уведомлений, а затем, через какое-то время, исчезает. Однако если закрыть приложение после того, как уведомление появилось в области уведомлений, оно не пропадает и остаётся висеть в области уведомлений и панели уведомлений "навечно" (до перезагрузки телефона, например). При этом в логах всё равно в этом случае выводится строка:

> TRYING TO KILL NOTIFICATION

а исключений никаких не выбрасывается.

В чём причина такого поведения? И как всё-таки решить эту проблему, сделать так, чтобы и после закрытия приложения уведомление исчезало?

Comment: Уведомление выведенное методом `startForeground` не может быть удалено до завершения режима foreground. Вызовите `stopForeground(true)` и оно должно удалиться.

Comment: @woesss, благодарю, этот метод - в точности то, что мне было нужно! оформите как ответ =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обязательное требование режима `foreground` сервиса - это уведомление, сигнализирующее о том, что он работает. Поэтому метод `startForeground` требует на вход `notification` и делает его не удаляемым до завершения режима `foreground`.

Когда `foreground` нам больше не нужен - мы можем вызвать метод `stopForeground`, передав ему флаг о необходимости убрать или оставить уведомление. Но в любом случае после вызова `stopForeground` уведомление можно удалить (даже если оно было выведено другим экземпляром сервиса, и этот факт используется как хак для сокрытия `foreground`).